# How to select specific keys only from JSON keeping its structure?

Tags: json, jq

I have JSON configuration of Grafana dashboard.
I want to get spicific keys like

```
.rows[].title
.rows[].panels[].title
.rows[].panels[].description
.rows[].panels[].format
.rows[].panels[].targets[].expr
```

and transform it to new JSON with following structure:

```
[
    {
        "row_title": ".rows[].title",
        "panels": [
            {
                "panel_title": ".rows[].panels[].title",
                "panel_description": ".rows[].panels[].description",
                "panel_format": ".rows[].panels[].format",
                "panel_exprs": [
                    {
                        "expr": ".rows[].panels[].targets[].expr"
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

Tried to do it with map(), but cannot understand how make nested arrays.

Comment: Please show (a reduced version of) your input JSON and (real) expected output JSON. Otherwise this is not really answerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are asking? Transforming the input array with all nested arrays and keeping only certain properties of each object? Any property not listed in the jq program will be ignored and dropped from the output.

```
map({
    row_title,
    panels: .panels | map({
        panel_title,
        panel_description,
        panel_format,
        panel_exprs: .panel_exprs | map({
            expr
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: That is! Make few changes, the final result is: 
jq '.rows | map({row: .title, panels: .panels | map({panel: .title, description, format, exprs: .targets | map({ expr }) }) })' node_exporter.json
Thanks!